# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC INDIRECT

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to run excel indirect function from c#. I used the following code but got the exception

> "A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   System.Dynamic.dll"

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

```
Excel.Range vehicle_makes_dropdown = xlWorkSheet1.get_Range("B2", "B101");
vehicle_makes_dropdown.Formula = "=indirect(A2)";
vehicle_makes_dropdown.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertInformation, XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, vehicle_makes_dropdown.Formula, misValue);

vehicle_makes_dropdown.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;
vehicle_makes_dropdown.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
```

Updated Code is

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wlb = app.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Templates2.xlsx");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet MySheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wlb.Sheets[1];


Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRange;

//  Get Subject 



// string subjetcs = string.Empty;
//List<Topics> lstsubject = PickSubject(out subjetcs);
AdminQuestionCommonModel objAdminQuestioncommonModel = new AdminQuestionCommonModel();
// _Question.BindQuestionDropDowns(objAdminQuestioncommonModel);
objAdminQuestioncommonModel.ExcelTopics = _Question.GetTopics(subjectId);

List<SubjectBO> lstTopics = GlobalService.GetAllTopicsandSubtopics(5, subjectId, 0); // get all topics of Subjects
//if (lstsubject.Count > 0)
if (lstTopics.Count > 0)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet IDSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wlb.Sheets[2];


    int rows = 1;
    int subrows = 1;
    IDSheet.Unprotect("123#");


    //foreach (var item in lstsubject)
    foreach (var Topic in lstTopics)
    {

        var TopicName = Topic.Topic_SubTopic.Trim();
        TopicName = TopicName.Replace(".", "_").Replace("&", "_").Replace(" ", "_").Replace("__", "_");

        // Add the header the first time through  
        IDSheet.Cells[rows, 1] = Topic.SubjectTopicId.ToString();
        IDSheet.Cells[rows, 2] = TopicName;

        //   List<SubTopics> lst = PickSubTopic(item.TopicName, item.TopicID);
        List<SubjectBO> lstsubtopics = _Question.GetSubTopics(subjectId, Topic.SubjectTopicId);

        int startindex = subrows;
        foreach (var subtopics in lstsubtopics)
        {
            IDSheet.Cells[subrows, 4] = subtopics.Topic_SubTopic;
            IDSheet.Cells[subrows, 5] = subtopics.SubjectTopicId.ToString();
            IDSheet.Cells[subrows, 6] = TopicName;
            IDSheet.Cells[subrows, 7] = Topic.SubjectTopicId.ToString(); 
            subrows++;
        }
        if (lstTopics.Count > 0)
        {
            wlb.Names.Add(TopicName, IDSheet.get_Range("D" + startindex + ":D" + (subrows - 1)));
        }
        subrows++;
        rows++;

    }


    wlb.Names.Add("Topics", IDSheet.get_Range("B1:B" + (rows - 1)));

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range Range = MySheet.get_Range("B2", "B800");

    Range.Validation.Delete();

    Range.NumberFormat = "Text";
    //Range.Cells.Value = lstsubject[0].TopicName.ToString();
    Range.Cells.Value = "Text";

    Range.Validation.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop
    , Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween
    , Formula1: "=Topics"
    );

    Range.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
    Range.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;



    oRange = MySheet.get_Range("c2","c3");

    oRange.Validation.Delete();

    oRange.NumberFormat = "Text";



    oRange.Validation.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop
    , Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween
    , Formula1: "=INDIRECT(B2)"
     );

    oRange.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
    oRange.Validation.IgnoreBlank = true;

    IDSheet.Protect("123#");
    //Range.Validation.InCellDropdown = true;
    //Range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 217, 217, 0));



    app.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: no also it works when i am getting data from Hard Code values..problem occur when i got the data from Database

Comment: Sorry ...A2 Contains List of items coming from another sheet..

Comment: Google "Excel error 1004".  A bazillion hits, you don't need another one.  Turning off auto-recalc ought to go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put double quotes around your cell reference inside the formula:
`vehicle_makes_dropdown.Formula = "=indirect(""A2"")";`

Answer (score -1):

```
oRange.Validation.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList,
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop,
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
    Formula1: "=INDIRECT(if(B2=\"\",A5000,B2))"
```

// see also http://user.qzone.qq.com/26149705/blog/1474296940

Comment: Please both correctly format and elaborate on your code. Add information how your code works and how it solves the question to improve the helpfulness future readers.

Comment: It would appear that when `Operator` is xlBetween, `Formula2` is required. Since your function call is missing the closing parenthesis, I'd imagine you just forgot to paste the rest. And, as jotasi said, please elaborate. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840078.aspx

Comment: see also user.qzone.qq.com/26149705/blog/1474296940